# Flash External Callback Error!

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook

I'm trying to acces a swf function from javascript using External Interface given by adobe and I get the following error.

```
SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller http://media.varheroes.com/flash/flashtest.swf cannot access http://apps.facebook.com/feline-frenzy/flashtest/.
at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_initJS()
at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/addCallback()
at flashtest_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Sadly apps.facebook.com does not have a crossdomain policy. My swf and my DOM lays there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a facebook Bridge Error they fixed it now!

Answer (score 0):

You can set *allowscriptaccess* to *always* when embedding the flash.

See http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html